# Extract floats from list of list of strings

Tags: python, list

```
[['1. (25, 32)'], ['2. (24.2, 31.5)'], ['3. (22, 34)'], ['4. (20.5, 34)']]
```

How to extract what's in between the parentheses as floats.
The output should be something like this:

```
[[25, 32], [24.2, 31.5], [22, 34], [20.5, 34]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to break the problem down into logical parts. For example, if you have *just* the string `(25, 32)`, can you create the desired result `[25, 32]` (or, a tuple, `(25, 32)`)? Can you get that string from the actual string that you have? Can you get the actual strings from the lists? Can you repeat this for each element in the outer list? **What part is actually the question**? Please note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a tuple to a list after extracting the tuple from the strings will consume a lot of memory and is not ideal. If you just want to get the strings of the tuple into floating numbers. You can first do a `str.split` and `eval`

```
[eval(j.split('. ')[1]) for i in alist for j in i]
[(25, 32), (24.2, 31.5), (22, 34), (20.5, 34)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always in this format, you can do:

```
your_input = [['1. (25, 32)'], ['2. (24.2, 31.5)'], ['3. (22, 34)'], ['4. (20.5, 34)']]
output = [[float(number) for number in elem[0].split(". ")[1].rstrip(")").lstrip("(").split(", ")] for elem in your_input]
```

output:

```
[[25.0, 32.0], [24.2, 31.5], [22.0, 34.0], [20.5, 34.0]]
```